# Using Pandas read_csv() on an open file twice

Tags: python, csv, pandas

As I was experimenting with pandas, I noticed some odd behavior of pandas.read_csv and was wondering if someone with more experience could explain what might be causing it.

To start, here is my basic class definition for creating a new pandas.dataframe from a .csv file:

```
import pandas as pd

class dataMatrix:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.path = filepath  # File path to the target .csv file.
        self.csvfile = open(filepath)  # Open file.
        self.csvdataframe = pd.read_csv(self.csvfile)
```

Now, this works pretty well and calling the class in my __ main __.py successfully creates a pandas dataframe:

```
From dataMatrix.py import dataMatrix

testObject = dataMatrix('/path/to/csv/file')
```

But I was noticing that this process was automatically setting the first row of the .csv as the pandas.dataframe.columns index.  Instead, I decided to number the columns.  Since I didn't want to assume I knew the number of columns before hand, I took the approach of opening the file, loading it into a dataframe, counting the columns, and then reloading the dataframe with the proper number of columns using range().

```
import pandas as pd

class dataMatrix:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.path = filepath
        self.csvfile = open(filepath)

        # Load the .csv file to count the columns.
        self.csvdataframe = pd.read_csv(self.csvfile)
        # Count the columns.
        self.numcolumns = len(self.csvdataframe.columns)
        # Re-load the .csv file, manually setting the column names to their 
        # number.
        self.csvdataframe = pd.read_csv(self.csvfile, 
                                        names=range(self.numcolumns))
```

Keeping my processing in __ main __.py the same, I got back a dataframe with the correct number of columns (500 in this case) with proper names (0...499), but it was otherwise empty (no row data).

Scratching my head, I decided to close self.csvfile and reload it like so:

```
import pandas as pd

class dataMatrix:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.path = filepath
        self.csvfile = open(filepath)

        # Load the .csv file to count the columns.
        self.csvdataframe = pd.read_csv(self.csvfile)
        # Count the columns.
        self.numcolumns = len(self.csvdataframe.columns)

        # Close the .csv file.         #<---- +++++++
        self.csvfile.close()           #<----  Added
        # Re-open file.                #<----  Block
        self.csvfile = open(filepath)  #<---- +++++++

        # Re-load the .csv file, manually setting the column names to their
        # number.
        self.csvdataframe = pd.read_csv(self.csvfile, 
                                        names=range(self.numcolumns))
```

Closing the file and re-opening it returned correctly with a pandas.dataframe with columns numbered 0...499 and all 255 subsequent rows of data.

My question is why does closing the file and re-opening it make a difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you open a file with

```
open(filepath)
```

a file handle *iterator* is returned. An iterator is good for one pass through its contents. So

```
self.csvdataframe = pd.read_csv(self.csvfile)
```

reads the contents and exhausts the iterator. Subsequent calls to `pd.read_csv` thinks the iterator is empty.

Note that you could avoid this problem by just passing the file path to `pd.read_csv`:

```
class dataMatrix:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.path = filepath

        # Load the .csv file to count the columns.
        self.csvdataframe = pd.read_csv(filepath)
        # Count the columns.
        self.numcolumns = len(self.csvdataframe.columns)


        # Re-load the .csv file, manually setting the column names to their
        # number.
        self.csvdataframe = pd.read_csv(filepath, 
                                        names=range(self.numcolumns))
```

`pd.read_csv` will then open (and close) the file for you.

PS. Another option is to reset the file handle to the beginning of the file by calling `self.csvfile.seek(0)`, but using `pd.read_csv(filepath, ...)` is still easier.

---

Even better, instead of calling `pd.read_csv` twice (which is inefficient), you could rename the columns like this:

```
class dataMatrix:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.path = filepath

        # Load the .csv file to count the columns.
        self.csvdataframe = pd.read_csv(filepath)
        self.numcolumns = len(self.csvdataframe.columns)
        self.csvdataframe.columns = range(self.numcolumns)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about the file iterator.  That makes sense.  I will make a change to pass the 'filepath' instead of the open file.  However, renaming the columns as you suggest at the end will replace the column names, meaning I lose the first row of data.

Comment: Then add `header=None` so the first row of data will be part of the data, not interpreted as column names.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about header=None...I am having issues getting that to work but that is a separate issue.  Thanks for answering my original question!  I was just curious about the lower-level, "behind-the-scenes" interaction that was causing the 'openfile' behavior.  Thanks!