# Combining multiple pandas read_csv and/or file.readline()

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a text-data file, that it is composed of many consecutive and alternating blocks of data, and each block is either with N rows and X columns or N+1 rows and Y columns.

My idea was to use `pd.read_csv` with two consecutive calls, the first using the option `nrow=N`, the second with `nrow=N+1`, but I have found this problem that I don't understand.

Let's consider this minimal example:

```
#header first line
#header second line
-2.000000000000e+00 7.853981633974e-03
-1.998000000000e+00 7.853981633974e-03
-1.999000000000e+00 1.570796326795e-05 8.214081241617e-13 8.222110115758e-18 6.069302089412e+00 3.450000000000e+07 3.077971152413e+03 0.000000000000e+00 0.000000000000e+00 -6.315974034994e+02 0.000000000000e+00 0.000000000000e+00 1.000000000000e+00 0.000000000000e+00 0.000000000000e+00 -1.000000000000e+00 8.526515773580e+06 2.736441000000e+03
```

This is the code that I am using to read the data:

```
import pandas as pd
fp=open('test.txt')
fp.readline()#let's skip first and second line
fp.readline()
q=pd.io.parsers.read_csv(fp,nrows=2,header=None,sep=' ',names=['x_ar','a_ar'])
```

Now, I was expecting that the result of a further:

```
In [4]: fp.readline()
```

would be the last line, but, I got an empty string.

```
Out[4]: ''
```

What's going on? How can I solve this problem?

PS. I know I could just iterate with `fp.readline`, but I am interested in a pandas solution.

Comment: I'm not sure `read_csv` is set up to handle being called multiple times on the same open file.  The best solution is to just preprocess your file and split it into multiple files.  As I understand it, your file is not a CSV file, but a concatenation of multiple CSV files.  `read_csv` is for reading CSV files, not concatenations of multiple CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

1. About the null string in the last `fp.readline()`:

> When you open a file with `open(filepath)` a file handle iterator is
>   returned. An iterator is good for one pass through its contents. So
>   `pd.io.parsers.read_csv(fp,nrows=2,header=None,sep='
>   ',names=['x_ar','a_ar'])` reads the contents and exhausts the
>   iterator. Subsequent calls to pd.read_csv thinks the iterator is
>   empty.
>
> Answer adapted from this
>   [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25943246/170005).

2. To handle comments that you have at the top of the file, you could pass, `comments='#'` like this:

> ```
> fp=open('../test.txt')
> pd.io.parsers.read_csv(fp,nrows=2,header=None,sep=' ',names=['x_ar','a_ar'], comment='#')
> ```

Your output then would be:

```
     x_ar   a_ar
0   -2.000  0.007854
1   -1.998  0.007854
```

Comment: The problem is not how to handle the first lines, but rather why the pointer in the file is not wgere it should be after the call to read_csv

Comment: Well, while i got the point,  to be precise, it doesn't exhaust the iterator. Try with two blocks of 1000 lines

Comment: Are you saying that the file structure makes the behavior different ?

Comment: Not the structure, but the length of each block (following my question, the number N). Indeed, in my original case, N=1000, (not two as my example) I found that the `readline` after the read_csv was pointing to a (pseudo)random line, in a (pseudo)random point in the middle of itself.

Comment: Well, frankly I'm finding it hard to believe you. After the end of the last `fp.readline()`, I did `fp.tell()`. That location and the total number of characters in the file match. (total no. of characters were calculated with `sum([len(i) for i in open('../test.txt').readlines()])` )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76353/discussion-between-fixxxer-and-thunder1123).